# plpgsql - bytes are not getting unpacked right

Tags: plpgsql

I wrote a function in plpgsql `unpack_numeric_bytes`, the most important part of the functions is:

```
FOR i IN 1..v_length LOOP
    v_val := v_val + (get_byte(v_bytes, v_byte_index) << v_bit_shift);
    v_bit_shift := v_bit_shift + 8;
    v_byte_index := v_byte_index + 1;
END LOOP;
```

It has worked fine until I came across value that it didnt decode correctly.. and it might be too obvious but I am not seeing it.

The call is: `select unpack_numeric_bytes(E'g\\363I\\274', array[4], 'f');`

From the code `v_length` is 4 bytes and it tries to decode `E'g\\363I\\274'`
Which comes up to : `{-1136004249}`.. I noticed that 
2^32 - 1136004249 = 3158963047, and that is the right answer I am looking for ! (tested it with python unpack function).

What is throwing it off? and what am I doing wrong? This is the first time the function failed me.

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out.. but can't post my answer yet. It needs to be casted to bigint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what the problem was:

```
select ('10111100000000000000000000000000'::bit(32))::integer;
int4 | -1140850688
-- versus
select (('10111100000000000000000000000000'::bit(32))::bigint);
int8 | 3154116608
```

Fixed this line:

```
v_val := v_val + (get_byte(v_bytes, v_byte_index)::BIGINT << v_bit_shift)::BIGINT;
```